# Java text not formatting properly

Tags: java

I just can't seem to figure out how to get java to format my output properly. The code snipet for output is: `System.out.format("\n %1s%20s%25s", intDf.format(i), df.format(monthlyPayment), df.format(totalPayment))`; the output appears like this:

`Interest Rate      Monthly Payment      Total Payment
 5              188.71                 11322.74
 5.125              189.29                 11357.13
 5.25              189.86                 11391.59
 5.375              190.44                 11426.11
 5.5              191.01                  11460.7
 5.625              191.59                 11495.35
 5.75              192.17                 11530.06
 5.875              192.75                 11564.84
 6              193.33                 11599.68
 6.125              193.91                 11634.59
 6.25              194.49                 11669.56
 6.375              195.08                 11704.59
 6.5              195.66                 11739.69
 6.625              196.25                 11774.85
 6.75              196.83                 11810.08
 6.875              197.42                 11845.37
 7              198.01                 11880.72
 7.125               198.6                 11916.14
 7.25              199.19                 11951.62
 7.375              199.79                 11987.16
 7.5              200.38                 12022.77
 7.625              200.97                 12058.44
 7.75              201.57                 12094.18
 7.875              202.17                 12129.97
 8              202.76                 12165.84`

I want all the values to line up at the first letter in their corresponding line. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your first column is more then one character wide. So when you say

```
System.out.format("\n %1s
```

That throws it off. The column name "Interest Rate" is 13 characters. So try

```
System.out.format("\n %14s
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment, I would use a `DecimalFormat` and a `NumberFormat` like

```
String[] headings = { "Interest Rate", "Monthly Payment",
        "Total Payment" };
for (String heading : headings) {
    System.out.print(heading);
    System.out.print("\t");
}
System.out.println();
double[] interestRates = { 5, 5.125 };
double[] monthlyPayments = { 188.71, 189.29 };
double[] totalPayments = { 11322.74, 11357.13 };
NumberFormat interestFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.000'%'");
NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
for (int i = 0; i < interestRates.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-13s\t%-15s\t%-13s%n",
            interestFormat.format(interestRates[i]),
            currencyFormat.format(monthlyPayments[i]),
            currencyFormat.format(totalPayments[i]));
}
```

Output is

```
Interest Rate   Monthly Payment Total Payment   
5.000%          $188.71         $11,322.74   
5.125%          $189.29         $11,357.13
```

Comment: To get the values onto the left hand side I actually just had to set it to %-5 and it lined up, thanks for the suggestion though it gave me a better idea on how System.out.format works and helped me find the answer

Comment: @user2636072 I added a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it from

```
  System.out.format("\n %1s%20s%25s", intDf.format(i), df.format(monthlyPayment), df.format(totalPayment));
```

to `System.out.format("\n %-5s%20s%25s", intDf.format(i), df.format(monthlyPayment), df.format(totalPayment));`

then changed the DecimalFormat to: `"'$'0.00"`